# Using a single Calculated field , can I get the number of weekdays calculated from the current month in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I have a requirement to do % of (Workdays till date) / (Total Workdays of the month). How can I create a "Calculated field" for this logic. I don't need to consider holidays or any sort. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick google search turned up this:
http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/calculating-the-number-of-business-days

> In the Calculated Field dialog box, do the following and then click
>   OK: Name the calculated field. In the example workbook, the calculated
>   field is named Number of Weekdays. In the formula field, create a
>   calculated field similar to the following:
>
> ```
> DATEDIFF("weekday", [Start Date], [End Date])
>
> - 2 * (DATEPART('week', [End Date]) -DATEPART('week', [Start Date]))
>
> + (IF DATENAME('weekday',[End Date]) = 'Saturday' OR DATENAME('weekday',[Start Date]) = 'Sunday'
>
> THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
> ```

In your example you take the difference between the first and the last of a month and calculate the working days by subtracting `2 * [number of weeks]` for the weekends. Once you have that value you can easily create the ratio you wanted.

Comment: Yup.. thank you. Me too got this. Tried it and it worked perfectly fine.